# Apache - Forbidden You don't have permission

Tags: php, android

I use ["HTTP Server powered by Apache" app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esminis.server.apache&hl=en) on android. I start the server and open 127.0.0.1:8000 on chrome, say:
Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Maybe there is a problem with my Apache config, but httpd.conf is empty.

Comment: This app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esminis.server.apache&hl=en ?

Comment: @FredGandt yes it is

Comment: Running HTTPD without a conf is a great way to have lots of issues.  Apache is configured not to show anything that hasn't got permissions set.  My guess is that Document Root is also empty, or else the Document Root is not set properly (could also be an issue with permissions on the DOCROOT folder, I guess)....

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey i not change anything from i install it, so i need to replace httpd.conf to original httpd.conf file?

Comment: According to [the only documentation I could find (quickly)](https://bitbucket.org/esminis/server/wiki/Home#markdown-header-http-server-powered-by-apache) the `.conf` is in path `[data directory]/conf/httpd.conf`. Is that where you're looking?

Comment: @FredGandt maybe yes if it Apache on dekstop, in this app the directory is in sdcard/htdocs/config/httpd.conf

Comment: Make sure the Document Root is specified and that there's a file in there that corresponds to the index file.  On a standard install this is something like [ DocumentRoot "/usr/local/www/apache22/data" ] and " DirectoryIndex index.html " ... ensure that index.html exists.  If the problem continues after this permissions (either filesystem or httpd document root configuration) is likely the issue.

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey thank you, yes it because i dont have index.html. i try to put index then i acess it from myip:myport/indexhtml. It works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Document Root is specified and that there's a file in there that corresponds to the index file. On a standard install this is something like [ DocumentRoot "/usr/local/www/apache22/data" ] and " DirectoryIndex index.html " ... ensure that index.html exists. If the problem continues after this permissions (either filesystem or httpd document root configuration) is likely the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same problem too with "HTTP Server powered by Apache" app on Android, however i take a look at ..htdocs/log/errors.log when starting the app, and i found DocumentRoot var was at ..htdocs/public, so the solution was create an index.html file over that directory so:

Put this content:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
  My page
</title>
</head>
<body>
  Hello <b>World!</b>
</body>
</html>
```

In a file called index.html

Copy or edit that file at your Android directory /storage/emulated/0/htdocs/public directory .. or simply .. //sdcard/htdocs/public, directory, which is the same anyway.

Then run you server in other device to test it (default your.ip.address:8000) or your.ip.address:8000/index.html And then it will work smooth and nice as expected. Please check my localhost example [webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TTko.png), which is working now with the index.html file at public directory